# Passing value to attribute in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an HTML element  with the style attribute for inline CSS.

```
<div style="border-color:aqua!important">
...
</div>
```

I want to be able to pass values such that "aqua" would be changed via Angular 2 interpolation so I tried this...

```
<div style="border-color:{{item.color}}!important">
...
</div>
```

But this isn't working

Comment: Try using [style]="border-color: item.color !important"

Comment: Nope. Isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<div [style.border-color]="item.color">..</div>
```

Comment: I tried without the "!important" and value is getting passed when I inspect but I need the "!important" to override cascading

Comment: Rewrote CSS so !important wasn't neccessary. Thank you very much